# Java: Printing out an object for debugging

Tags: java, json, tostring, infinity, divide-by-zero

I would like an easy way to print out a java object, or to say it another way, serialize an object as a string.  I would like to see the values of all variables contained within the object, and if there are more objects (like a list or whatever) it should print out the stuff in that object as well.  Basically, it would be something like JSON encoding, but JSON doesn't support infinity, and I need to see if there is infinity or NaN in one of the double or float values.

How can I do this?

Comment: If it's a class you wrote, just override the `ToString()` method appropriately.

Comment: I didn't write it.  And that would take a long time to manually do it, even if I could.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dumping a java object's properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603013/dumping-a-java-objects-properties)

Comment: What do you mean by "but JSON doesn't support infinity"?

Comment: @Amir see sec 2.4 of the spec - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627  (NaN and infinity aren't supported by JSON officially)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to serialize to JSON as it [now supports NaN and +/- infinity](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/detail?r=345)

Comment: This works beautifully, way better than the reflection in the other answer.  I used `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues().serializeNulls().create(); System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj));` which let me see nulls, NaN and infinity values.

Comment: This doesn't work quite well with mocked objects or static variables

Answer (score 12):

More often than not [ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(Object)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) works great. It wont work when doing Maps though.

Comment: ...which is a part of apache's commons-lang

Comment: the link appears to be broken. Please verify if it has been moved to a new location.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`:

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myObject)
```

Beautify:

```
new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true).writeValueAsString(myObject)
```