# Does Java have a method to inspect object type?

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, object, dump

In Javascript, if you want to inspect some object in chrome,

`console.log(object)` will printout variables, and methods about the object.

Ruby also has `object.inspect` which returns basic information about the object.

What code should I use in Java to inspect an object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the code you need to inspect Java objects is in the [java.lang.reflect](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) package.

You'll have to write a fair bit of code yourself using that API though.

Apache's [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) is somewhat easier.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the Java Reflection [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

For example, try this:

```
Class c = object.getClass();
System.out.writeln("Looks like you have a "+c.getCanonicalName());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it at Runtime from you code, something like `console.log` is provided by [`log4j`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/). The information you'll log can be retrieved via [Java Reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

For dumping Java objects, look at the [answers over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603013/dumping-a-java-objects-properties) for various ways of doing it. I'd use [`XStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603013/dumping-a-java-objects-properties) for its ease of use and maturity.

If you need external tools to look into the VM, tools like [Java VisualVM(`jvisualvm.exe`)](http://visualvm.java.net/) and [JConsole(`jconsole.exe`)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) are very useful.