# Is there a way to save the state of a object?

Tags: java

In c I could simply do something like fwrite(file,&object,(sizeof object)); to save all the verbals in the object.  Is there a way to do this in java??

Comment: [Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html)

Comment: Note that doing that in C is *very* brittle - and vanilla binary serialization is pretty brittle in Java, too...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dumping a java object's properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603013/dumping-a-java-objects-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your class implement the `Serializable` interface, then you can serialize objects using an `ObjectOutputStream`:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
  public String name = "";
  public int age = 0;
}
```

Serialization:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.name = "Foobar";
p.age = 42;

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/test.txt"));
oos.writeObject(p);
oos.close();
```

Deserialization:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/test.txt"));
Person p = (Person)ois.readObject();
System.out.println(p.name + " is " + p.age + " years of age.");
ois.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can save the state of object in Java using Serialization or Externalization.