# Access Data from any object

Tags: java, list, iteration

I have an Object1(pojo class) with 4 keys
and another Object2 has 7 keys now i wanna read each value in List in loop as well as `List<Object2>`

Is there any utilities Available for this kind of iterations

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Do you mean fields/members with keys?

Comment: If I read your extremely vague question right, this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603013/dumping-a-java-objects-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#Java).

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class MyObject {
  String x = "hello";
  int y = 42;
  String z = "world";
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    for (Field f : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
      System.out.println(f.getName() + ": " + f.get(obj));
    }
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
x: hello
y: 42
z: world
```

Now, that works, but reflection is generally a lot slower than just accessing the fields. So, unless you need your code to be generic and work on arbitrary objects, you're better off accessing the fields by hand.

Comment: Vague answer to vague question.

Comment: How to use reflections can u show me an example.

Comment: Can't we access private variables

Comment: Yes but you need a bit more work. Look for `setAccessible()`.

Comment: Thanks Vlad it is working fine. Any disadvantages bcoz of this

Comment: In all but very rare cases, instead of using reflection, you'll need to redesign instead.