# Can I access class variable from created own annotation

Tags: java, annotations

how can I access class variable from my custom annotation in Java language? Is it possible?

```
@MyAnno
public class MyClass() {
    String name;
    String surname;
    ....
} 

public @interface MyAnno{
 // I want to access MyClass and get the class variable etc name, surname.
}
```

Comment: why do you want this ?

Comment: I want to printed all variable and value of variable when printed output. I dont want see hascode of object. You might think as case class in scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get the annotated class with plain java. You have to use tool like [org.reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) or [annotation indexer](https://github.com/jenkinsci/lib-annotation-indexer) to get a list of all annotated `java.lang.Class`es.

Comment: Hi, thanks you for answer. I want to create case/data class in java as scala case class and etc. When I printed object to output I don't see hashcode , ı want to display all variable of class and your value to special format.

Comment: Once you have a reference, it will be possible to dump even private fields using reflection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603013/dumping-a-java-objects-properties

Comment: Thanks you for answer again. I understand not possible doing by annotation.  I  will do with. reflection