# Dumping the contents of JNI structures to console

Tags: java, console, java-native-interface

Is there a simple/standard way for dumping the contents of JNI types, such as `jobject` or `jclass`, to either console output or file, from the C++ environment? For example, printing the field names and types of a given `jclass`? Is there an exising JNI facility or a library that could help to achieve this?

Comment: JNI allows access to the full introspection techniques available in Java. AFAIK, you'll have to code that yourself. What do you mean by "offsets"?

Comment: Thanks @manuell. Never mind the offsets, I confused it with something else.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you looking for [`javap -s`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html)?

Comment: @TomBlodget looking for an easy way to introspect/dump JNI classes during JVM runtime, from C++ code interacting with the JVM. Ideally, something like a function `dump_jobject(jobject* myObj)` (for example), that will nicely print the contents of the jobject, and could be called at runtime - either by adding a call in the C++ code itself, near the code to be debugged, or by adding it to IDE's variables watch view.

Comment: JNI doesn't have classes. (The C++ interface is a thin wrapper around the C interface.) It is far easier to do anything in Java than via JNI. I suggest you grab a reflection library that dumps objects like you need and simply call that at interesting points in your JNI code. (I've never used it but [XStream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/603055/2226988) looks like it might do the job.)

Comment: @TomBlodget thanks for clarifying and pointing towards XStream, I'll give this a try.