# Size of the class in Java

Tags: java, memory

I have read this article http://btoddb-java-sizing.blogspot.com/
Author explain how to calculate Objects size in Java. For example:

```
import jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.debug.ObjectSizeCalculator;

public final class Perfomance {

    static int number;

    static int anotherNumber;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ObjectSizeCalculator.getObjectSize(new Integer(2)));
    }
}
```

This code will show 16 because new object takes 12 bytes and inside Integer we have int(4 bytes) `12+4 = 16.`

But consider this code:

```
System.out.println(ObjectSizeCalculator.getObjectSize(Integer.class));
```

Now its size 56 , moreover

```
 System.out.println(ObjectSizeCalculator.getObjectSize(Object.class));
```

Its show 288. How does it work. How allocated memory depends on class ?

Comment: In my machine `Integer.class` is 8840, `Object.class` is 288. Are you sure that you print a correct result?

Comment: @dehasi Yes , in my machine x64 ubuntu 16.04 jdk 1.8.0_171 with OOPS its show 56 for Integer

Comment: I have 56 for  `Byte.class` class if it helps in your investigation. I have jdk 1.8.0_144 on mac os. My guess `Integer` is `final` class,  and this info helps to JIT to make optimizations. Keep in mind, you check sizes of  `Class<T>` objects

Comment: Class object contains list of interfaces, classes, directly implemented methods, runtime annotations, fields. Look at this topic for dump, make few experiments and forget abouut it - it's just low-level magic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603013/dumping-a-java-objects-properties